# How I can add the simple mode to codemirror ( Angular 8)?

Tags: angular, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

Currently,I would like to create a simple text editor for my DSL and I use for that Angular 8 and CodeMirror (@ctrl/ngx-codemirror), my problem is how I can integrate the following (https://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html) simple mode to my angular application in order to have a new mode.

```
/* Example definition of a simple mode that understands a subset of
 * JavaScript:
 */
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("simplemode", {
  // The start state contains the rules that are intially used
  start: [
    // The regex matches the token, the token property contains the type
    {regex: /"(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?(?:"|$)/, token: "string"},
    // You can match multiple tokens at once. Note that the captured
    // groups must span the whole string in this case
    {regex: /(function)(\s+)([a-z$][\w$]*)/,
     token: ["keyword", null, "variable-2"]},
    // Rules are matched in the order in which they appear, so there is
    // no ambiguity between this one and the one above
    {regex: /(?:function|var|return|if|for|while|else|do|this)\b/,
     token: "keyword"},
    {regex: /true|false|null|undefined/, token: "atom"},
    {regex: /0x[a-f\d]+|[-+]?(?:\.\d+|\d+\.?\d*)(?:e[-+]?\d+)?/i,
     token: "number"},
    {regex: /\/\/.*/, token: "comment"},
    {regex: /\/(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?\//, token: "variable-3"},
    // A next property will cause the mode to move to a different state
    {regex: /\/\*/, token: "comment", next: "comment"},
    {regex: /[-+\/*=<>!]+/, token: "operator"},
    // indent and dedent properties guide autoindentation
    {regex: /[\{\[\(]/, indent: true},
    {regex: /[\}\]\)]/, dedent: true},
    {regex: /[a-z$][\w$]*/, token: "variable"},
    // You can embed other modes with the mode property. This rule
    // causes all code between << and >> to be highlighted with the XML
    // mode.
    {regex: /<</, token: "meta", mode: {spec: "xml", end: />>/}}
  ],
  // The multi-line comment state.
  comment: [
    {regex: /.*?\*\//, token: "comment", next: "start"},
    {regex: /.*/, token: "comment"}
  ],
  // The meta property contains global information about the mode. It
  // can contain properties like lineComment, which are supported by
  // all modes, and also directives like dontIndentStates, which are
  // specific to simple modes.
  meta: {
    dontIndentStates: ["comment"],
    lineComment: "//"
  }
});
```

Here is the content of my app.component.html .

```
<ngx-codemirror [(ngModel)]="code" [options]="options"></ngx-codemirror>
```

I would like to add this mode to my angular application and after I modify it according to my grammar, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

in your_component.html

```
<ngx-codemirror
  [(ngModel)]="code" [options]="options"
  #codeMirror
></ngx-codemirror>
```

in your_component.ts

```
@ViewChild(CodemirrorComponent, {static: false})
  private cmComponent: CodemirrorComponent;

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.cmComponent.codeMirrorGlobal.defineSimpleMode("simplemode", {
  // The start state contains the rules that are intially used
  start: [
    // The regex matches the token, the token property contains the type
    {regex: /"(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?(?:"|$)/, token: "string"},
    // You can match multiple tokens at once. Note that the captured
    // groups must span the whole string in this case
    {regex: /(function)(\s+)([a-z$][\w$]*)/,
     token: ["keyword", null, "variable-2"]},
    // Rules are matched in the order in which they appear, so there is
    // no ambiguity between this one and the one above
    {regex: /(?:function|var|return|if|for|while|else|do|this)\b/,
     token: "keyword"},
    {regex: /true|false|null|undefined/, token: "atom"},
    {regex: /0x[a-f\d]+|[-+]?(?:\.\d+|\d+\.?\d*)(?:e[-+]?\d+)?/i,
     token: "number"},
    {regex: /\/\/.*/, token: "comment"},
    {regex: /\/(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?\//, token: "variable-3"},
    // A next property will cause the mode to move to a different state
    {regex: /\/\*/, token: "comment", next: "comment"},
    {regex: /[-+\/*=<>!]+/, token: "operator"},
    // indent and dedent properties guide autoindentation
    {regex: /[\{\[\(]/, indent: true},
    {regex: /[\}\]\)]/, dedent: true},
    {regex: /[a-z$][\w$]*/, token: "variable"},
    // You can embed other modes with the mode property. This rule
    // causes all code between << and >> to be highlighted with the XML
    // mode.
    {regex: /<</, token: "meta", mode: {spec: "xml", end: />>/}}
  ],
  // The multi-line comment state.
  comment: [
    {regex: /.*?\*\//, token: "comment", next: "start"},
    {regex: /.*/, token: "comment"}
  ],
  // The meta property contains global information about the mode. It
  // can contain properties like lineComment, which are supported by
  // all modes, and also directives like dontIndentStates, which are
  // specific to simple modes.
  meta: {
    dontIndentStates: ["comment"],
    lineComment: "//"
  }
});
 }
```

then you can specify in options of codemirror

```
this.options = {
   mode: "simplemode"
}
```

or you can set it via

```
this.cmComponent.codeMirror.setOption('mode', "simplemode");
```

also don't forget to include

```
import 'codemirror/addon/mode/simple';
```

I do import in main.ts of the project